# Delphi: Use public procedures from a dynamic form

Tags: delphi, dynamic, sender

I have a Delphi XE+ application with 3 forms, 2 of them created dynamically, like so:

- `form_main` is triggering `form_equip`
- `form_equip` is triggering `form_certif`

`form_main` -> `form_equip` -> `form_certif`

1'st: Open `form_equip`

```
procedure Tform_main.button_equip_addClick(Sender: TObject);
var 
  form_equip: Tform_equip;
begin
  form_equip:= Tform_equip.Create(Self);
  form_equip.equip_id:= 0;
  form_equip.ShowModal;
  FreeAndNil(form_equip);
end;
```

On `form_equip` I have a public `procedure has_changes`

2'nd: Open `form_certif`

```
procedure Tform_equip.button_certif_addClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  form_certif: Tform_certif;
begin
  form_certif:= Tform_certif.Create(Self);
  form_certif.index:= 0;
  form_certif.ShowModal;
  FreeAndNil(form_certif);
end;
```

Now, when I press OK button from `form_certif`

```
procedure Tform_certif.button_okClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //do something...

  form_equip.has_changes; //this public procedure from form_equip is not visible because form was created as local var on form_main
end;
```

The question is, how can I transmit the sender/parent name to `form_certif` so can I see the public procedures and variables from `form_equip`?

A simple way is to declare inside `unit_equip` as global:

```
var 
  form_equip: Tform_equip
```

but I avoid to do this because `form_equip` is made to be opened dynamically in multiple windows with different names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass all needed information from `form_equip` to `form_certif`. That way `form_certif` is decoupled from any dependence of `form_equip`.

```
procedure Tform_equip.button_certif_addClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  form_certif: Tform_certif;
begin
  form_certif:= Tform_certif.Create(nil);
  try
    form_certif.index:= 0;
    // Pass all other needed variable values to form_certif
    // including callback methods
    form_certif.Has_Changes_Method := Self.Has_Changes();
    if form_certif.ShowModal = mrOk then
    begin
      // take care of changes
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(form_certif);
  end;
end;
```

And this is how it would look in the `form_certif` unit:

```
type
  THas_Changes_Method = procedure of Object;
  TForm_Certif = class(TForm)
  ...
  private
    FIndex: Integer;
    FHasChanges: THas_Changes_Method;
  public
    property Index: Integer read FIndex write FIndex;
    property Has_Changes_Method: THas_Changes_Method read fHasChanges write fHasChanges; 
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the information as a parameter in the constructor. Declare the constructor like this:

```
constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; const ParentName: string);
```

In the implementation of the constructor, make a note of the name that was passed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating forms in code, you can add custom constructor to the form and pass other form as parameter.

```
Tform_certif = class(TForm)
...
protected
  form_equip: Tform_equip;
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; Aform_equip: Tform_equip); reintroduce;
end;

constructor Tform_certif.Create(AOwner: TComponent; Aform_equip: Tform_equip);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  form_equip := Aform_equip;
end;
```

So now you can call `form_equip.has_changes`, because it is a field that you have initialized during construction of your `Tform_certif` form and it points to particular instance of `Tform_equip` that created this particular instance of `Tform_certif`.

```
procedure Tform_certif.button_okClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //do something...

  // test whether form_equip is assigned to avoid AV by calling methods on nil object 
  if Assigned(form_equip) then form_equip.has_changes;
end;
```

And to create your `Tform_certif` you would use following code

```
procedure Tform_equip.button_certif_addClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  form_certif: Tform_certif;
begin
  form_certif:= Tform_certif.Create(Self, Self);
  form_certif.index:= 0;
  form_certif.ShowModal;
  FreeAndNil(form_certif);
end;
```

There is also variation of above constructor code, where you only need to send one parameter and then test in constructor whether `AOwner` it is of `Tform_equip` type and you don't need to change code in `button_certif_addClick` for using that kind of solution.

```
Tform_certif = class(TForm)
...
protected
  form_equip: Tform_equip;
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
end;

constructor Tform_certif.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  if AOwner is Tform_equip then form_equip := Tform_equip(AOwner);
end;
```